# How to solve local HTML web taking time to play videos from me computer

Tags: html, css

I recently wrote a local HTML web code with video-backgrounds which change everytime the wepage is reloaded, but the videos take time to play and a white screen is showed in place of videos until they are loaded, and even after they start playing, they keep lagging, is there a way to fix this ?`

```
    <script>
      // function to generate random int inside a given range
      function getRandomInt(min, max) {
          return Math.floor(Math.random() * (7 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
      }
      var video = document.getElementById('vidtest');
      var sources = video.getElementsByTagName('source');
      var videoUrlsMp4=["Resources/videos/vid.mp4", "Resources/videos/vid1.mp4", "Resources/videos/vid2.mp4", "Resources/videos/vid3.mp4", "Resources/videos/vid4.mp4", "Resources/videos/vid5.mp4", "Resources/videos/vid6.mp4"];
      var random_nr = getRandomInt(0, videoUrlsMp4.length-1);
      sources[0].src = videoUrlsMp4[random_nr ];
      video.load();
  </script>`
```

Comment: The background issue could probably be fixed by providing a `poster` image for the video element. But what exactly you mean by _"even after they start playing, they keep lagging"_, is rather unclear. Maybe the videos are simply too big/have too high a bitrate to load at the necessary speed.

Comment: @CBroe so should I compress them to load faster ?

Comment: _If_ that is the issue ... we can't really tell, based on just the vague verbal description of the issue we have so far.